# How to upgrade Fedora OpenVZ container over SSH?

Tags: ssh, fedora, upgrade, openvz

what is the standard procedure for upgrading Fedora (18 to 19) that runs as an OpenVZ container on my VPS via SSH? Can I simply use `fedup` or does the admin have to perform the upgrade from outside of the container via some OpenVZ utils?

Comment: Ask the provider about this first.

Comment: The provider offers very little support and I feel this is a question the general public may be able to answer rather than bugging their small team.

Comment: I meant just ask them if they think using `fedup` will be a problem.  Keep in mind you can be left with an un-usuable, offline system...